# ssis script task add filename and sheetname to the table

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm using `SqlBulkCopy` to dump data into the table. I want to add the `filename` and `sheetname` to the table. `filename` and `sheetname` fields are located last in the table. Below is my code.

```
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    string directoryname =  file.Directory>name;
    string filename = file.Name;

    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFolderPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\""; 
 
    OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    cnn.Opne();

    DataTable dtsheet = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

    foreach (DataRow drSheet in dtSheet.Rows)
    {
        if (drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("xlnm"))
            sheetname = drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    
         OleDbCommand con = new OleDbCommand("select * from [" +sheetname+"]", cnn);
         OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(con);

         con.CommandTimeout = 0;
    
         using (OleDbDataReader reader =  con.ExecuteReader()
         {
             using (SqlBulkCopy dbc = new SqlBulkCopy(myadoconn)
             {
                 dbc.Batchsize = 5000;
                 dbc.DestinationTableName = "Table1";
                 dbc.WriteToServer(reader);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using bulk copy inside a script task? Why not just use bulk copy in a standard SSIS dataflow? I suggest performing a single update on the table at the end to set these values in an execute SQL task

Comment: this is a dynamic table consists of 150 columns and 500000 rows, that's the reason used bulk copy. I'm new to .net. How to write update statement to above code?

Comment: filename and sheetname fields are located last in the table ? if you have 500000 so it is located in the 499999th row ? and since it is containing  150 columns logically that row has 148 columns with NULL values I suppose. Can you explain more ?

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. Ignore last or first...   create table table1 (filename varchar(10), sheetname varchar(10), column1 varchar(10),column2 varchar(10), column3 varchar(10),....column200 varchar(10)

Answer (score 0):

Since the filename and sheetname are not part of the data you're reading from the Excel files, you'll need to manually add them before inserting the data into the table.

So you need to create a `DataTable` that mirrors the schema of your destination table and then use the data reader to fill that table. Add the filename and sheetname to each row, and then use `SqlBulkCopy` to write the `DataTable` to the destination table.

```
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    string directoryname = file.Directory.Name; 
    string filename = file.Name;

    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + file.FullName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\"";

    using (OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        cnn.Open();

        DataTable dtSheet = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

        foreach (DataRow drSheet in dtSheet.Rows)
        {
            if (drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("$")) 
            {
                string sheetname = drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                OleDbCommand con = new OleDbCommand("select * from [" + sheetname + "]", cnn);
                con.CommandTimeout = 0;

                using (OleDbDataReader reader = con.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataTable.Columns.Add("filename", typeof(string));
                    dataTable.Columns.Add("sheetname", typeof(string));
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
                    {
                        dataTable.Columns.Add("column" + i, typeof(string));
                    }

                    // Read data from the Excel file into the DataTable
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
                        row["filename"] = filename;
                        row["sheetname"] = sheetname;
                        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
                        {
                            row["column" + (i + 1)] = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
                        }
                        dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
                    }

                    
                    using (SqlBulkCopy dbc = new SqlBulkCopy(myadoconn))
                    {
                        dbc.BatchSize = 5000;
                        dbc.DestinationTableName = "Table1";
                        dbc.WriteToServer(dataTable);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amira. If i want to add header into 'Headerrow' table and  data  into 'DataTable' then what changes required in above code?